# How is the program block controlling the clock output in this code?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

This is a simple SV program (I know an arbiter is much more complex, pardon me for naming this as one), but I don't know how the line `repeat(4) @ar.cb;` keeps controlling the entire clock.  If I comment out that line, the clock stops even though I have put it in an 'always' block inside the top module. I can't understand how this works.

```
testbench.sv

interface arb_if(input bit clk);
    logic [1:0] request;
    logic [1:0] grant;
    logic reset;
    clocking cb @(posedge clk);
        output request;
        input grant;
    endclocking

    modport DUT(input request,clk,reset,output grant);
    modport TB(clocking cb,output reset); endinterface

program automatic test(arb_if.TB ar);
    initial begin
        ar.reset <= 1;
        ar.cb.request<=$urandom;
        $display("[%0t]Request is sent",$time);
        repeat(4) @ar.cb;
        $display("[%0t]Grant=%0d",$time,ar.cb.grant);
    end endprogram

module top;
    bit clk;
    always #5 clk=~clk;
    arb_if arb(clk);
    test tb(arb);
    arbit a1(arb,clk); endmodule

design.sv

module arbit(arb_if.DUT arbiter,input bit clk);   always @(posedge clk)
      if(arbiter.reset==0)
        arbiter.grant<=2'bxx;
      else
        #1 arbiter.grant<=arbiter.request; 
endmodule
```

And in the design, the grant does not get assigned till the next cycle even if I use a blocking assignment (unless I give `#1`, in which case it does, of course after the delay).

I am struggling with understanding the synchronous circuit timings.  It'd be a great help if someone can clear this up for me.

Without `#1`:

[image: Without #1]

With `#1`:

[image: With #1]

Comment: Also, Do you know why that #1 delay causes the program to function properly ? Is it beacuse the read and write cannot happen simultaneously or that design reads input value just before the active clock edge ? (Or delay time in this case)

Comment: My question is since request is already assigned, why not assign it to grant at the end of the time frame ? Why the extra clock cycle delay ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `program` terminates the simulation.

From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section *24.3 The program construct*:

> When all initial procedures within a program have reached their end,
>   that program shall immediately terminate all descendent threads of
>   initial procedures within that program. If there is at least one
>   initial procedure within at least one program block, the entire
>   simulation shall terminate by means of an implicit call to the $finish
>   system task immediately after all the threads and all their descendent
>   threads originating from all initial procedures within all programs
>   have ended.

With the `repeat` statement, the simulation ends at time 35.  It waits for 4 positive edges of `clk`, then implicitly calls `$finish`.

Without the `repeat` statement, the simulation ends at time 0.  It doesn't wait for any `clk` edges, then implicitly calls `$finish`.

Comment: BTW, the use of `program` blocks in SystemVerilog is strongly discouraged http://go.mentor.com/programblocks. Just use a `module` instead.